# In rails view using simple-form Is there any way to restrict selecting future date in date picker?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datepicker, ruby-on-rails-5, simple-form, slim-lang

I am using common date-picker in rails view using simple form gem.
I need to restrict user by selecting future date in simple form itself

```
= f.input :start_date, label: 'Select Date', wrapper_html: {class: 'col s12 '}, input_html: {class: 'datepicker'}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you change the input to a `date_field`, you can add a `min` option. With that option, you can set Date.today so you can only set today and onward as the date. It would look something like this:

```
<%= f.date_field :start_date, min: Date.today %>
```

Or, if you want dates from tomorrow onward, you can set it like this:

```
<%= f.date_field :start_date, min: Date.tomorrow %>
```